# How to access local MYSQL database from a VPS

Tags: mysql, database, vps

Hey guys i'm new to this. I have a PC running win 10 and installed mysql. I have a VPS and it runs UBUNTU 14.04.5 LTS. i have registered in www.noip.com for dynamic dns. i simply wanna access my local database from VPS like

mysql -u door -h mylocaldatabase.hopto.org -P3306  -p

but i get this error:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mylocaldatabase.hopto.org' (101)
what should i do?

Comment: Did you try to ping your PC from VPS?
Do you have remote connections opened in mysql? By default they are closed (afair)

Comment: No there is no ping. what should i do?

Comment: When you cant ping your PC from VPC it meens your machine is not visible to the world. Check firewall, check router (forward ports if needed)

Comment: i created an inbound rule for port 3306 isn't it enough? and i did port forwarding too